# Get names in a tuple nested inside another tuple

Tags: c#, reflection

How to get names in a tuple in c# using reflection if one tuple is nested inside another tuple?
For example like this

```
public static void M(((int n1, uint n2) o1, ((int p1, (int w1, uint w2) p2, uint p3) q1, ((int x1, uint x2) r1, byte r2) q2) o2) k) {}
```

Through the TupleElementNamesAttribute attribute, I can get an array of all value names.

```
ParameterInfo parameterInfo;
parameterInfo.GetCustomAttribute<TupleElementNamesAttribute>().TransformNames;

//"o1", "o2", "n1", "n2", "q1", "q2", "p1", "p2", "p3", "w1", "w2", "r1", "r2", "x1", "x2"
```

But it is not clear how to associate an element of a tuple with its name in the array because there is no index.

Comment: What do you mean by " associate an element of a tuple with its name"? What do you want to get out of this? A dictionary with the element names as keys? What would the values be?

Comment: @Charlieface This is incorrect, I found a detailed [explanation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/19946). "pre-order depth-first" here refers to when the number of items in a `ValueTuple` exceeds 7, the names of additional items included in the `TRest` item will be traversed first. (And they will be traversed again as a normal `ValueTuple` item) For the 1st to 7th items, their names should be added to the list first, and then each item should be checked before entering recursion if it is another `ValueTuple`.

Comment: @shingo You're right it does appear to be breadth first in the normal case. Docs probably need cleaning up.

Comment: @shingo This is some absolute mind blowing. I still can't figure out where the extra nulls on your link come from. How to detect a pattern in this so that you can automatically parse it. Maybe there is some api that will allow you to get the array index for each tuple element?

Comment: @viruseg They represent the items in the `TRest` item, these items are traversed twice. You can read the source code: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Compilation_WellKnownMembers.cs#L842